# Конвертация одной структуры в другую с одинаковыми полями, но с разными пакетами

Tags: golang

У меня есть структура `Api`, которая лежит в пакете `tgsrc`. Также есть контекстная структура `apiContext`, которая лежит в пакете `src`. Два разных пакета, но есть одна и также структура `Api` и `ApiContext`.

```golang
package tgsrc
type Api struct { /* … */ }
```

```golang
package src
type apiContext struct { *tgsrc.Api }
```

Я хочу конвертировать одну структуру в другую на примере:

```golang
type justAnotherType struct {
    botCtx *apiContext
}

func New(bot *tgsrc.Api) *justAnotherType {
    return &justAnotherType{
        botCtx: apiContext(bot),
    }
}
```

Мне выдает ошибку о том, что нельзя совмещать эти две структуры, и я не понимаю почему, ведь по сути это одно и то же, только отличие в пакете.

Не спрашивайте, зачем это нужно :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же `*tgsrc.Api` (неверное именование, кстати; должно
быть `API`) *встроен* в `apiContext`.  Так
и пишите:

```golang
return &justAnotherType{
    botCtx: apiContext{ Api: bot },
}
```